# Add maximum possible edges from given set to the graph with nodes capacity

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have some extension for my previous question, so I ask it as a separate one.

Problem: given N nodes, each of them has a limit for it's own degree, for example degree of the node (1) can not be higher that 10 (but can be less, of course), degree of the node (2) can not be higher that 3, etc. Also, set of possible edges, connecting these nodes is given.

Tasks:
A) On these nodes build graph with maximum possible edges.
B) Estimate the max. number of edges in graph, without actually building it.

Example of the problem:

Nodes: 1(max. degree 2), 2(max. degree 3), 3(max. degree 3), 4(max. degree 1), 5(max. degree 2).

Possible edges: (1-2), (1-4), (1-5), (2-3), (2-5), (3-4)

Would be happy to see any hints/recommendations.

Comment: At least mention the graph should be simple this time

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter in this case, since the set of edges is given.

Comment: Ah, I missed that part. Never mind then. This potentially makes the problem much harder than the first one, maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you set all of the max degrees to 1, you have the problem of constructing a maximum matching in a non-bipartite graph, which has polynomial-time algorithms but that are tricky to implement. In your shoes, I'd try integer programming. You can express this pretty straightforwardly as an integer program:

```
maximize sum_{e in E} x_e
subject to
for all v in V, sum_{e ~ v} x_e <= d_v
for all e in E, x_e in {0, 1}
```

where `d_v` is the max degree of vertex `v` and `x_e` indicates whether `e` is chosen or not.

For a quick approximation that will never underestimate, you can relax the constraints `x_e in {0, 1}` to `0 <= x_e <= 1` and solve the resulting linear program.